# How to make a page render in browser in Github?

Tags: html, github

If I have an `.html` page in my project and want to show that as it's renders what should I do? Is there any specific URL for this reason?

Update:
In Github I mean!

Comment: Duplicate: [how-to-see-an-html-page-on-github-as-a-normal-rendered-html-page-to-see-preview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8446218/how-to-see-an-html-page-on-github-as-a-normal-rendered-html-page-to-see-preview)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use [GitHub HTML Preview](http://htmlpreview.github.com/)

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using the following steps:

1. Rename the .html file to index.html
2. Go to setting and enable Github Pages for master branch.
3. Go to the website:

```
   https://username.github.io/repo-name/
```

Here you put your username and repository name containing the html file

Answer (score 0):

This solution only for chrome browser. I am not sure about other browser.

1. Add "Modify Content-Type Options" extension in chrome browser.
2. Open "chrome-extension://jnfofbopfpaoeojgieggflbpcblhfhka/options.html" url in browser.
3. Add the rule for raw file url.
   For example:

   - URL Filter:           https:///raw/master//fileName.html
   - Original Type:        text/plain
   - Replacement Type: text/html
4. Open the file browser which you added url in rule (in step 3).