# How to use CSS in Markdown?

Tags: css, markdown

I want to use a CSS class in a Markdown file.

For instance, `<i class="icon-renren"></i>` (from `fontawesome`) should be displayed as an icon if I import its CSS file in HTML.

Is there any solution in Markdown?

Answer (score 58):

you can use html in your mark down as normal.

```
<style>
mark{
    color:red;
}
</style>

<mark>what is DataBase</mark>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works well for hugo markdown renderer.

Comment: It has some errors and does not recognize the style tag. Why?

Comment: This is not working with VS Code MD preview at present (Version: 1.67.2)

Comment: @EttoreGalli, have you reported it to VSCode's GitHub?

Answer (score 13):

The simplest way to [add custom css styles is to use Pandoc attributes syntax (which can convert Markdown to html, pdf, pppt and more)](https://lifelongprogrammer.blogspot.com/2019/01/best-way-to-style-markdown-with-pandoc.html)

```
Heading Identifiers:
### Red text title {#identifier .red}

Fenced Code Attributes:
{.red .numberLines startFrom="1"}

Inline Code Attributes:
`red text`{.red}

Bracketed Spans:
[This is *some red text*]{.red}

Link Attributes:
![alt text](the.jpg){.center}
```

Answer (score 9):

**Edit:** If you want to include FontAwesome icons in R Markdown (or Shiny Apps), there is now a package to do exactly that: https://github.com/rstudio/fontawesome. The answer below is more general (not limited to R Markdown or FontAwesome) but somewhat of a workaround.

---

Not tested in `Gitbook` but i hope this works just as well as on `github`.

Here is one way for using **Font Awesome** icons in an `html` document written in `markdown` (with `knitr`). To be able to display the resulting `html` document correctly on `github`, I used a workaround by linking to `htmlpreview.github.io/?` (as *niutech* described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12233684/4798582)):

1. Download **Font Awesome** [here](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) and unzip into your local repository where you also saved the `.Rmd` file.
2. Tell markdown which `.css` file to use by adding `font-awesome-4.4.0/css/font-awesome.css` into the header of your `.Rmd` file. *Note:* you might need to change the version number to something other than 4.4.0.
3. Make sure to specify `self_contained: no`. *jmcphers* explained [here](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/228) that this option keeps `pandoc` from combining multiple files into a single file, which somehow messes up the paths specified in the `font-awesome.css` file.
4. In your `.Rmd` document, include a link to `http://htmlpreview.github.io/?/url_to_html_on_github` where you replace `url_to_html_on_github` with the url to your `html` file on github.

Here is a **minimal working example** (`fa-5x` just makes the icon larger, as described in [these examples](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/)):

```
---
title: "Title"
author: "Author"
date: "DATE"
output: 
  html_document:
     css: font-awesome-4.4.0/css/font-awesome.css
     self_contained: no

---
<i class="fa fa-renren fa-5x"></i>

To preview the correctly rendered html file, click 
<a href="http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/FlorianWanders/FAonGitHub/blob/master/MWE.html" title="preview on htmlpreview.github.io" target="_blank">here</a>.
```

And the resulting preview (see also [this github repository](https://github.com/FlorianWanders/FAonGitHub/blob/master/MWE.md)):

[image]

Answer (score 4):

First of all, most of the markdown implementations allow you to use [plain html](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html)

Where as some markdown implementations offer you an additional syntax for attributes, like ids and classes (e.g. [php-markdown](https://michelf.ca/projects/php-markdown/extra/#spe-attr) `{#id .class}` for block elements)

As far as I know, fontawesome always needs the leading `<i>`-tag. Other iconfonts (like [weloveiconfonts](http://weloveiconfonts.com)) add the icon to a existing html tag `<h2 class="zocial-dribbble">text</h2>`, in markdown-extra: `## text {.zocial-dribbble}`.

Comment: I want to use `fontawesome` in `Gitbook`, any solution ?

Comment: How do you reference the stylesheet?

Comment: Any global css will be applied.