# Adding custom CSS style in img

Tags: markdown, hugo

Currently, I’m using hugo material theme : https://github.com/digitalcraftsman/hugo-material-docs

When I write the following content markdown

```
![practice-signup-1](/images/practice-signup-1.png)
```

Hugo will generate the following HTML code

```
<p><img src="https://investing.jstock.co/images/practice-signup-1.png" alt="practice-signup-1"></p>
```

However, I wish to add the following style to my img tag

```
<p><img src="https://investing.jstock.co/images/practice-signup-1.png" alt="practice-signup-1" style="max-width: 100%; width: 50%; height: auto;"></p>
```

I was wondering, how can I achieve so?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change image size Markdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14675913/how-to-change-image-size-markdown)

Comment: Also possibly a duplicate of [How to use CSS in Markdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27174946/866026)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create shortcode for it.

Make your own shortcode in `/themes/your-theme-dir/layouts/shortcodes/img.html`.

```
<p><img src="{{ .Get 0 }}" alt="practice-signup-1" style="max-width: 100%; width: 50%; height: auto;"></p>
```

and then use that short code in your post:

```
{{< img https://investing.jstock.co/images/practice-signup-1.png >}}
```

Other way, you can add style in css file instead of create inline style.

Answer (score 2):

You can put raw HTML in markdown files.  So if you have an image that you want special styles in, just paste the `<img src..` code in your markdown file.