# How to import a css file in a markdown?

Tags: css, markdown

I have tried `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">` in markdown but that didn't work. Is there a way to do that?

I know using a style tag can work, but I wonder how to import a css in markdown. So I think the problem is different with [How to use CSS in Markdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27174946/how-to-use-css-in-markdown) . The link doesn't mention importing css in a markdown.

Comment: @tacoshy I know using a style tag can work, but I wonder how to import a css in markdown.

Comment: How are you generating HTML from your Markdown source? What tool are you using?

Comment: @Chris I don't generate HTML, just see the preview in vscode.

Answer (score -2):

It should work, you can add css in three different ways

1. inline style

example : `<p style="color: red">Username </p>`

2. internal styling with the help of  tag
   example : `<style> p {color: 'red'}</style>`
3. external link
   Using link tag, we can load css into html file

   `<link rel="stylesheet" href="<source-link>" />`

Comment: 1st) This is a commentary and not an answer. 2nd) link-only answers do not fit the guidelines as an answer. 3rd) Your link does not apply here, it is not an HTML question.

Comment: @tacoshy is this fine now.

Comment: You still miss the point. We do not talk about HTML files we talk about **Markdown** which is a completely different Markup language! So throwing HTML solutions around here is incorrect.