# Correct way of linking raw github file?

Tags: github, markdown

In my github repo's `Readme.md`, I'd like to link to several raw html files.

I can do that by

```
[](./output_HTML/marham.html)
```

But in my github page, the HTML cannot be rendered directly. For example, for my file (https://github.com/cqcn1991/Wind-Speed-Analysis/blob/master/output_HTML/marham.html), it will display:

[image]

What would be a good way to link my file, so the HTML can be directly rendered?

I know one alternative is to use `rawgit`. That is, to manually change the link into

```
[](https://cdn.rawgit.com/cqcn1991/Wind-Speed-Analysis/master/output_HTML/marham.html)
```

But I'm not sure if this is the right approach? Or if there are better way than to manually do this?

Comment: see the `raw` button at the top right corner of the file? also, the `view raw` link in the file itself? use that. (but that's going to be rendered as plain text, as github does not set the type of the file in the headers)

Comment: @njzk2 As you said, both of the `raw` and `view raw` render the HTML as plain text, and that's not what I want. I want the page.

Comment: you can use [github pages](https://pages.github.com/) if you need to host actual content

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8446218/how-to-see-an-html-page-on-github-as-a-normal-rendered-html-page-to-see-preview

Answer (score 0):

Since rawgit.com is shutting down you want to use [combinatronics.com](https://combinatronics.com) it is an alternative for [rawgit.com](https://rawgit.com)

It is a drop in replacement, so for your example:

```
[](http://cdn.combinatronics.com/cqcn1991/Wind-Speed-Analysis/master/output_HTML/marham.html)
```