# p5 js sketch works locally but not on github

Tags: github, p5.js

I have several p5.js sketches, all of which work locally, but none will display on GitHub pages. Here is the html:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="libraries/p5.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="sketch1.js"></script>
<style> body {padding: 0; margin: 0;} </style>
</head>
<body>
```

and here is the javascript:

```
function setup() {
 createCanvas(500,500);
 background(250, 212, 210);
 strokeWeight(4);
}

function draw() {
 line(mouseX, mouseY, pmouseX, pmouseY);
 if (mouseIsPressed == true) {
  stroke(250, 3, 80);
 } else {
  stroke(110, 164, 249);
} 

 }
```

Comment: Can you please provide a link to the github page? Also, you need to familiarize yourself with [the developer tools](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/javascript/developer-tools). Chances are your error is there.

Comment: I'll review the developer tools now. [here](https://bethanyrennard.github.io/hello-wurld/) is the GitHub page

Comment: The GitHub page you just linked to does not contain any runnable p5.js code, nor do you add it to your page.

Answer (score 0):

If you are accessing the .html file from a GitHub repository, it will not actually display the rendered html page itself, but only the source code. If you would like to preview the html file on GitHub, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8446218/how-to-see-an-html-page-on-github-as-a-normal-rendered-html-page-to-see-preview) answer and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6551446/can-i-run-html-files-directly-from-github-instead-of-just-viewing-their-source) answer address that question.

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you've just forgotten to add a directory to your repository (or perhaps forgotten to push the changes to github). I see 6 files in your repo that include p5.js: `110-click.html`, `116.html`, `114.html`, `index copy.html`, `127-click.html`, and `129-click.html`. All of these include `libraries/p5.js`, but there's no `libraries` directory in your repository.

I'm guessing you need to use `git add libraries` from the repo root to add this directory (and then commit and push to github).